# Array to function parameters

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm using the [node.js Redis library](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) and I'm attempting to bulk-subscribe to many keys. I've got an array which is dynamic i.e

```
var keys {'key1','key2',...,'keyN'}
```

and I want to feed each index in as parameters to `subscribe` in the Redis library which takes one or more string(s). I've tried the apply function in JS using..

```
redisClient.subscribe.apply(this,keys);
```

but it doesn't cause a subscription. Any suggestions on how I can get over this issue?

Comment: For future reference: [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Spread_operator)

Answer (score 2):

Your example data is totally invalid JS, but I'm assuming you have it correct in your code.
You need to set the proper function context:

```
redisClient.subscribe.apply(redisClient, keys);
```